# Calculate Completed Credits and Attempted Credits to reach a specific Completion Ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, combinations

I'm attempting to come up with a formula that solves the amount of Completed Credits and Attempted Credits needed to achieve a Completion Ratio of .67 The formula for Completion Ratio is Completed Credits / Attempted Credits.

As an example, let's say I currently have 28 Completed Credits out of 43 Attempted Credits, this would result in me having a Completion Ratio of .65. If my target Completion Ratio by the end of the semester is to be at .67, I would need to Attempt 3 more Credits and actually Complete those 3 Credits. By the end of the semester I would have a .67 Completion Ratio (28+3)/(43+3)=31/46=.67 Completion Ratio.

Now, how could I produce a formula to know how many Completed Credits and Attempted Credits I would need based on my current Completed Credits and Attempted Credits to achieve a bare minimum of .67 Completion Ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a Current Ratio of $a:=\frac{p}{q}$. If we plan completing the remaining credits that attempt. Then we require that we take $x$ more classes such that

$$ \frac{p+x}{q+x}=0.67$$

However, obviously this is an unrealistic assumption to assume you will clear all remaining credits (especially if $a\ll 1$). If we clear the remaining credits using our current clear rate, we have that for $x$ classes, we will pass at least $b\ge 0.67$ of them. Hence our solution for $x$ becomes

$$ \frac{p+bx}{q+x}=0.67$$

Comment: Ok so if X is the amount of credits I need to attempt and also complete, I've isolated x to X = (-pq + .67q^2)/(-.67q+1). If I use the the numbers in my example I would have X = (-(28)(43) + .67(43)^2)/(-.67(43)+1) and which leads to x = -1.25 pretty sure my math is off because attempting -1.25 additional credits and completing them would not bump me up to a .67 completion ration. (28+-1.25)/(43+-1.25) = .64 Completion Ratio

Comment: which of my models are you using? x is always equal to the number of credits attempted. in my first equation we assume that we clear all credits we attempt so we get the simple equation. in the second equation, $x$ is the attempted credits only.

Comment: so what you did was use the second equation, but assumed you will have a 100% clearance ratio of the remaining $x$ classes you take.

Comment: Okay it appears my original solution had a mistake, if we clear courses at the same rate we used to clear them (at 0.65) we will never reach a clear rate of 0.67. Hence we need a clear rate large than than 0.67 to see how long it would take to reach it.

Comment: Ahh my apologies, I got confused. At this point, I'm assuming all hours attempted need to be completed, so I will use the first formula. Thanks!